# AttributeError: object has no attribute 'ordered' when iterating a dictionary of lists of formsets

Tags: python, django, list, templates, attributeerror

I have A dictionary called FormDic. The Values of the dictionary are lists and the lists contain formsets. I have double checked that this is the case 100 different ways.

In my template i have the following:

```
{% for key, ItemList in FormDic.items %}
  {% for Formset in Itemlist %}
xxxxx
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

the x's are just placeholder. Now if I refer to the formset in any way, {{Formset}} {{Itemlist.0}}, whatever.... it throws a

```
AttributeError: 'Item' object has no attribute 'ordered'
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm losing my mind on this.

```
Traceback:

      File "C:\Users\a.schamroth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.6.egg\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\a.schamroth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.6.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\a.schamroth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.6.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\temp\python\projects\test1\getdata\views.py", line 133, in BudgetView
    return render(request, 'getdata/budgetmachine.html', {'FormDic':FormDic })
  File "C:\Users\a.schamroth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.6.egg\django\shortcuts.py", line 36, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\a.schamroth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.6.egg\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\a.schamroth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.6.egg\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\a.schamroth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.6.egg\django\template\base.py", line 175, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\a.schamroth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.6.egg\django\template\base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\a.schamroth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.6.egg\django\template\base.py", line 943, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\a.schamroth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.6.egg\django\template\base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\a.schamroth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.6.egg\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 155, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\a.schamroth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.6.egg\django\template\base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\a.schamroth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.6.egg\django\template\base.py", line 943, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\a.schamroth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.6.egg\django\template\base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\a.schamroth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.6.egg\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 67, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\a.schamroth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.6.egg\django\template\base.py", line 943, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\a.schamroth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.6.egg\django\template\base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\a.schamroth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.6.egg\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 211, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "C:\Users\a.schamroth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.6.egg\django\template\base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\a.schamroth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.6.egg\django\template\base.py", line 999, in render
    return render_value_in_context(output, context)
  File "C:\Users\a.schamroth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.6.egg\django\template\base.py", line 978, in render_value_in_context
    value = str(value)
  File "C:\Users\a.schamroth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.6.egg\django\utils\html.py", line 371, in <lambda>
    klass.__str__ = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_str(self))
  File "C:\Users\a.schamroth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.6.egg\django\forms\formsets.py", line 64, in __str__
    return self.as_table()
  File "C:\Users\a.schamroth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.6.egg\django\forms\formsets.py", line 404, in as_table
    forms = ' '.join(form.as_table() for form in self)
  File "C:\Users\a.schamroth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.6.egg\django\forms\formsets.py", line 68, in __iter__
    return iter(self.forms)
  File "C:\Users\a.schamroth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.6.egg\django\utils\functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\a.schamroth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.6.egg\django\forms\formsets.py", line 136, in forms
    for i in range(self.total_form_count())]
  File "C:\Users\a.schamroth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.6.egg\django\forms\formsets.py", line 112, in total_form_count
    initial_forms = self.initial_form_count()
  File "C:\Users\a.schamroth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.6.egg\django\forms\models.py", line 574, in initial_form_count
    return len(self.get_queryset())
  File "C:\Users\a.schamroth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.6.egg\django\forms\models.py", line 636, in get_queryset
    if not qs.ordered:
AttributeError: 'Item' object has no attribute 'ordered'
```

View

```
   if request.user.is_authenticated:
    U=request.user
    BudgetCatagoryFormset=modelformset_factory(BudgetCatagory, fields=('order','name','total_cost', 'detail'), widgets={"total_cost":TextInput()}, extra=0)
    ItemFormset=modelformset_factory(Item, fields=('name','detail','layout','unit','unit_price', 'unit_description', 'total_cost', 'QTY','param1','param2','param3', 'cost_ave', 'cost_max', 'cost_min', 'enName'), widgets={}, extra=0)
    if request.method=='POST':
        print("hi")
    else:

        if not BudgetCatagory.objects.filter(user_id=U.id):
            BudgetCatagory.objects.createCatagory(U, 1,
                                                    "שלד קומפלט",
                                                    "שקל למטר",
                                                    "single",
                                                    "normal",
                                                    "שלד",
                                                    "שטח",
                                                    "Sheled",
                                                    "Sheled")
            BudgetCatagory.objects.createCatagory(U, 2,
                                                    "חשמל קומפלט",
                                                    "שקל למטר",
                                                    "single",
                                                    "normal",
                                                    "חשמל",
                                                    "שטח",
                                                    "Electricity",
                                                    "Electricity")

        #import pdb
        #pdb.set_trace()

        Items=Item.objects.filter(budgetcatagory__user_id=U.id)
        Catagories=BudgetCatagory.objects.filter(user_id=U.id)
        #Constants=BudgetConsts.objects.all()

        #import pdb
        #pdb.set_trace()

        #initializes ave max and min unit costs from db
        for item in Items:
            C=BudgetConsts.objects.get_or_create(name=item.name)
            item.cost_max = C[0].max_val
            item.cost_ave = C[0].ave_val
            item.cost_min = C[0].min_val
            item.save()


        #import pdb
        #pdb.set_trace()

        FormList=[]
        FormDic={}
        #CatFormDic={}
        for catagory in CatagoryOrder:
            FormList=[]
            subset=Items.filter(parent=CatagoryOrder[catagory])
            #Catsubset=Catagories.filter(name=CatagoryOrder[catagory])
            if subset:
                #CatFormDic[CatagoryOrder[catagory]]=BudgetCatagoryFormset(queryset=Catsubset, prefix="Cat"+CatagoryOrder[catagory])
                for item in subset:
                    FormList.append(ItemFormset(queryset=item, prefix=item.name))
                FormDic[Catagories.filter(name=CatagoryOrder[catagory])[0].enName]=FormList


        #import pdb
        #pdb.set_trace()

        Constants=BudgetConsts.objects.get(id=1)
         #{'DicList':DicList}{'FormDic':FormDic, 'CatFormDic':CatFormDic }
        return render(request, 'getdata/budgetmachine.html', {'FormDic':FormDic })
    return redirect(request, 'getdata/budgetpage.html')
else:
    return redirect('/login'
```

Thx

Comment: Have you tried `FormDic.items()`?

Comment: This is inside the template. No braces in django template language as far as I know

Answer (score 2):

```
ItemFormset(queryset=item, prefix=item.name)
```

It doesn't make sense to this. The `queryset` must be a queryset, (e.g. `Item.objects.all()`), not an individual model instance.

Comment: This comment solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Alasdair!!!
 You solved the issue.

Following your post, I changed the line to

```
FormList.append(ItemFormset(queryset=subset.filter(id=item.id), prefix=item.name))
```

and it solved the problem.

Many many thanks